# Binding to observable collection getting element onTapp

Tags: binding, windows-8

i use a observable collcetion to bind data to a GridView (with an itemTemplate). The template includes an item that can be rightTapped. Is there any nice way to get the element (the one in the observable collection) in the rightTapped event handler?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes , youcan get the value from senderitem.datacontext (you would need some typecasting).